# Building executable from perl scripts programs using PAR on Activestate Windows

Tags: perl

I am used to build windows executable programs from perl scripts using Activestate PDK; now I would like to give a try to the PAR way to do the same thing - still using Activestate distribution:

>

> This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 2 (v5.12.2) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-t
>   hread

The documentation states:

>

> Combines scanning, zipping and loader-embedding:
>
> % pp -o out.exe src.pl         # self-contained .exe
>    % out.exe                      # runs anywhere on the same OS

but I am unable to find any executable pp.exe, pp.com o whatever.

Sure, PAR installed, version 1.002

Any idea about what I am possibly overlooking/ignoring/forgetting?

Many thanks!

Comment: Use PAR::Packer. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948405/how-to-compile-a-perl-script-pl-to-a-windows-executable-exe-with-strawberry

Answer (score 0):

After installing PAR::Packer module, you should find pp.bat in your Perl folder under /site/bin - for me, this location is c:\perl\site\bin\pp.bat.

Comment: No PAR::Packer Activestate module is available for perl 5.12 64 bit

Comment: Daniel: So install mingw from PPM and then install PAR::Packer from CPAN!