# How do I create an executable from Perl modules?

Tags: macos, perl, command-line, module, binary

I have a Perl module [CSS::Minifier](http://p3rl.org/CSS%3a%3aMinifier) that I need to make executable (command line utility) and use it in my Mac app, but I don't know if it's even possible.

Is there any way I can create a standalone binary from this module and use it from Terminal on a Mac?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237286/how-can-i-compile-my-perl-script-so-it-can-be-executed-on-systems-without-perl-it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948405/how-to-compile-a-perl-script-pl-to-a-windows-executable-exe-with-strawberr

Comment: On a mac, you can be fairly confident perl is already installed on the system, so there's no real need to make a binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look into the [PAR::Packer](http://p3rl.org/PAR%3a%3aPacker) module and its [pp](http://p3rl.org/pp) command line utility which will take a Perl script and turn it into a binary, fully loaded with any prerequisites needed.