# Installing PAR::Packer on Windows, dmake error 255

Tags: windows, perl, par, packer

I am trying to create a binary of a perl script for Windows, and I cannot afford commercial applications such as perl2exe and Active Perl Dev Kit (I am aware there are trial versions).

Because of this I have installed strawberry perl on a Windows XP SP3 32bit Virtual Machine to try and compile my source file; something that I was easily able to do on Linux.

Strawberry perl installs fine however when I try to install the PAR::Packer module from cpan, I get the following errors:

```
dmake: Error code 129, while makeing 'ppresources.coff'
dmake.EXE: Error code 255, while making 'subdirs'
  RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.013.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.EXE -- NOT OK
```

I have googled extensively, but as of yet haven't been able to find a solution, any help is greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: I haven't tried in Strawberry perl (alas, the project started before that was available), but I have used ActiveState's community version of perl and installed PAR::Packer for generating binaries.  If that's an option, you may want to try that.  You have to install most of PAR::Packer from cpan and not their PPM repos though.

Comment: Hmm I will give that a shot, I have tried Active Perl on my Windows 7 64bit, however I had similar dmake related issues. Still can't hurt to try can it? Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Well I managed to get pp installed but install Active perl -> cpan -i App::cpanminus -> cpanm --force PAR::Packer...

But now I can't get the Tk module installed :/

Comment: Have you tried using ppm to install Tk?  I have the best results relying on ppm for needed modules unless they are too old or don't install for other reasons (i.e. PAR::Packer).

Comment: I did get i sorted in the end, I believe it was by adding a repository to PPM : ) 

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Report this as a bug here: https://rt.cpan.org/Dist/Display.html?Name=PAR-Packer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding answer to aggregate comments above for future searchers:

Here's what works for me building on Windows systems.

1) Use ActiveState Perl 5.x (I've used 5.10 through 5.14).

2) Use PPM to install all packages you can from ActiveState PPM repository.

3) Fall back to CPAN to actually install PAR::Packer and any other requirements not in the ActiveState PPM repository.