# Batch File to Compress Certain Directories with 7zip?

Tags: windows, batch-file, 7zip

Just a request for help with batch programming.  Need to do periodic backups of certain folders and was wondering how I would achieve that.

Goal: To Scroll through a directory and compress certain folders with a certain name.

Code Logic:

```
  //For all directories in folder
  for /d %%X in (*) do (
    if ( %%X != tag_****** )
        "7z.exe" a -ttar "%%X.tar" "%%X\"
  )
```

.

```
  for %%X in (*.tar) do 
    "7z.exe" a -tgzip "%%X.tgz" "%%X"
```

How would I differentiate between folder names in batch if it is possible?

ex: compress tag_aaa111 , skip tag_aaa111_v2 , skip all folders without prefix "tag_"

condition is that the directory starts with tag_ and has exactly 6 chars after that.

Been stuck trying to figure out this. Thanks for the help.

edit: code, clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you care about the language? If you wanted to use PERL you could do something like:

```
while(<*>){
  if(-d && m/^tag_/){
    system("7zip $_"); # Change to whatever compress command you need
  } else {
    #other condition for other files and non matching directories
  }
}
```

Where the system will make a system call with whatever parameters are inside of it. The -d will specify whether the file is a directory, and the m// is a regex that matches against the specified pattern

Comment: would I be able to have windows scheduler automatically run perl scripts to automate the script every night? not very familiar with perl

Comment: As long as you have perl installed. You should be able to schedule any type of script or executable to run. [scheduling a perl script](http://serverfault.com/questions/267013/scheduling-a-perl-script-with-output-redirection) has an explanation

Comment: interesting. do you know if perl has a cli executable i can download? im trying to avoid installing anything.

Comment: It comes pre-installed on many unix flavors, but in windows you'd probably need to install the interpretor as it has a bunch of libraries and such. If installing software on the target machine is a problem (but you could do the development on a machine where installation isn't), you can try something like this [compiling perl to exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948405/how-to-compile-a-perl-script-pl-to-a-windows-executable-exe-with-strawberr) to make an executable.

Comment: yeah I dont have admin rights to the host machines but i'll definitely take a look into it if the batch doesn't work.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Windows' [`FOR`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and [`IF`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) batch file commands. Basically, it should be possible to write something like this:

```
for /D %%f in (*) do (
    set dirname=%%f
    if "%dirname:~0,4%"=="tag_" (
        7z ... %dirname% ...
    )
)
```

<sub>untested :)</sub>

Comment: oh perfect. so this code block would replace my code block one. and i assume that the if statement "7z ... %dirname% ..." would be this line: "7z.exe a -ttar %dirname%.tar %dirname%" ?  and how does the dirname sort directories out with exactly 10 chars in the name?