# Perl to generate one executable file for a script which uses any number of modules and libraries

Tags: perl

I am working on creating an agent in perl which does several actions. It uses several modules which are in .pm format and also few libraries. Now i want to convert it as one executable file so that i can install in n number of servers by copying that single file. Is it something i can achieve in perl? I am just a beginner in perl, perhaps my question might sound dumb but it will teach me something.

Comment: duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446685/how-can-i-deploy-a-perl-python-ruby-script-without-installing-an-interpreter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237286/how-can-i-compile-my-perl-script-so-it-can-be-executed-on-systems-without-perl-i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pp`](https://metacpan.org/module/pp) script provided with [`PAR::Packer`](https://metacpan.org/release/PAR-Packer) is able to create single-file executables. An example from its page:

```
pp -o foo foo.pl bar.pl   # Pack 'foo.pl' and 'bar.pl' into 'foo'
```

Comment: Thanks, i am looking for answer something like that. But let say if i am able to generate a single executable file using pp, then  can i run it in my other linux servers (of same arch type) without installing any module from CPAN such as PAR::PACKER

Answer (score 3):

Some modules are included with Perl, so even though they're separate modules, they will work on other Perl installs without installing those modules. These include `File::Copy`, `File::Find`, `Time::Piece`.

You can see the listing of all standard modules on the [Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org) home page. Be sure to set the drop down version field (located on the left side) to the version that you're using. It goes all the way back to Perl 5.8.8 which is on Solaris.

It is entirely possible that the modules you need are already included in the standard Perl distribution, so there's no need to worry. Sometimes, you can substitute a non-standard module that's being used for one that's a standard module with little rewriting.

Some modules include compiled C code and can't be redistributed. They must be compiled on the machine they'r running on and installed. However, most modules are pure Perl modules, and can be redistributed with a program.

If a module isn't a standard module, and it's a pure Perl module, there are two ways it can be redistributed:

- Perl has an `@INC` list that says what directories to search for when you search for modules. There's a Perl [use lib](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) pragma that allows you to add directories. You could include modules as sub directories for your program, and then zip up the entire structure. Users would unzip the entire directory tree which would include your program and the modules you need. By the way, the default `@INC` usually includes the current directory.
- The other way is to append the modules to your program and then remove the `use` statement for that module (since it's now part of the file). This is a bit tricky, but it means a single program file.

Just remember that a module might require another module, so check thoroughly.

---

Another thing you can do is check for the module, and if it isn't there, download it via CPAN. Testing is easy:

```
BEGIN {
    eval {
        require My::Module; Module->import( LIST );
    };
    if ($@) {
        die qq(Module doesn't exist);
    }
}
```

Of course, doing a `die` is sort of silly because `use` would do that. However, it might be possible instead of dying to load the module via the [CPAN module](http://perldoc.perl.org/CPAN.html#PROGRAMMER%27S-INTERFACE) programmer's interface. I've never done that, and I don't know people who have. But, it is possible.

So, your best bet is to check to see if your program uses standard Perl modules, and if not, see if you can modify the program to use them. For example, if your program uses `Archive::Zip`, you might be able to modify it to use `IO::Uncompress::Unzip` and `IO::Compress::Zip` instead.

Otherwise, your choice is to try include those modules for installation (and watch for recursiveness and non-Pure Perl modules) or to try to detect that a module isn't installed, and programmatically install it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a bit complicated.

The nature of Perl makes it practically impossible to compile a perl script in most use cases, so that a single executable could be distributed (with *executable* in the Windows sense). There are ways to do something similar, but sadly I don't know them.

But you can actually embed the Perl interpreter inside any C application, including the Perl source (your scripts + modules). When you statically link all C libraries, this should work as well. You can then use the Perl API to call your scripts.

If all of the servers you target are guaranteed to run the exact same OS, using the exact same libraries, and are preferably a *nix of some sort, it would be possible to pack all required files into an archive and write an install script. It is possible to write self-extracting shell scripts that contain the archive they are about to unpack. Same goes with perl, using the special `__DATA__` command and the `DATA` filehandle:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print for <DATA>;
__DATA__
1
2
3
```

prints

```
1
2
3
```

Works great for piping data to `tar` as well.

You should include all dependent modules and all compiled libraries into the file and figure out a metadata system to install all files to the correct place.

As a general rule, software should rather be compiled on the target system itself, than just copying the binary files. It is too easy to overlook architecture differencies, configuration files or special registration entries hidden from view.

If you have to target different systems, it might be better to write a script that delegates the bulk of the installation to `cpan` or whatever perl package manager you prefer. This will be more flexible than hard-coding filepaths.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cpan install Foo::Bar
 cpan install Acme
 cpan install ...
 # etc.
```

I would stick with that.

The most elegant solution would be to create your own package or distribution like the ones you download from CPAN. As you would include a metadata file referencing all your dependencies, cpan would figure out everything by itself and do possibly neccessary compilation. I don't think this exactly is a beginners topic, but it would give you max flexibility and maintainability (easy upgrades!). This should make it fairly easy to include some installation tests.

This is just for starters, I am sure the internet or somebody else with more knowledge will elaborate.